# Is Method overloading is also known as static polymorphism?

Tags: java

Iam just newbie to java
In the below code I have oveloaded print method between two different classes

Based on object at runtime only corresponding print method will be executed.If my understanding is right then how can we say method overloading is considered to be static ploymorphism

```
class Parent
{
    private int arg;
    public void print(int arg)
    {
        this.arg=arg;
        System.out.println(arg+"printed");
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{

    private String arg;
    public void print(String arg)
    {
        this.arg=arg;
        System.out.println(arg+"printed");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Parent p1=new Parent();
        Child ch=new Child();
        p1.print(1);
        ch.print("String");
    }

}
```

Please clarify me.Thanks in advance

Comment: _Based on object at runtime_ - **NO**. Java binds at _compile time_. As which specific method is called is decided at compile time, **all** polymorphism is "static" as you put it. It is only the `class` on which the method is called that changes.

Comment: @BoristheSpider *all polymorphism is "static"*. That sounds a bit incorrect to me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ChetanKinger the point I was trying to make is that methods are bound at compile time and therefore that is "static" (in the OP's terminology). What is dynamic is the class on which the **same** method is called. You're right though - it's not the more elucidating comment I've ever written.

Comment: What you did isn't really any different than having the two `print()` implementations in the same class. At least in Java-land. There isn't overloading in JS or Python lands, so you actually do get the option of rolling dynamic dispatch by hand. Which made me realize, you're really asking about *dispatch*.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this , may clear your doubts about how polymorphism works
[Can't access object in the array java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533269/cant-access-object-in-the-array-java/26533520#26533520)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is compile-time(static) polymorphism - given that you could write code such as :

```
Child ch=new Child();
ch.print(2015);
ch.print("String");
```